# getting number of every patters of combination of ascii characters in c

Tags: c

I have this string `abcpdxypabcdc` I like this

abc=2 //repeated number of times

p=2   //...

d=2   //...

xy=1  //...

c=1   //...

Since its length will be known. In function I will get pointer having pointing to `abcpdxypabcdc` string and length of string which in this case will be 13.
I like algorithm for it. I have tried it but I like to know what will be the correct to proceeding to solving these problems if I like to do it with pointers. I need explanation how to solve these types of problems

I think I need to maintain some struct with `index` where the each pattern start and a number that contains number of times the pattern is found in string so far.
Plus second loop to check each array of struct contains duplicated items. But I like to know what is the correct way of solving these coding examples.

Comment: So you want to generate all permutations of sub-strings and determine the frequency of each?   It applies some type of map of string to count.  You can use the original string if you (store a pointer or offset, size) to express each permutation.

Comment: @AllanWind `You can use the original string if you (store a pointer or offset, size) to express each permutation` can u please clarify this. and what do u meant by `map of string`

Comment: @AllanWind thanks for comment

Comment: A map is an abstract data structure that stores the relation between a key and a value.  In your case, the key is the permutation (string) and the value is the count.  You can implement a map with a hash table.  Now, what I told you was you store the permutation, like "a" by malloc 2 bytes.  An alternative implementation would be to store it has struct { unint8_t offset, uint8_t len } where offset is the offset into your original string so "a" would be stored as {0, 1}.

Comment: @AllanWind basically I meant in question pattern containing consecutive chars like `abc` I don't want   `abp` or `abd`, etc. its not permutations. I was wrong. look at my question